# Why does the writer use "that songs" instead of "those songs"?

Tags: adjectives

> Such a crime
> ... Well, let's face it: in many ways it is . That songs of the quality of "Sparrows" or "Lucky Smile" should be obliged to wait 30 years for a release.

Extract from a leaflet introducing the Rag Dolls comp called "Such a crime"

I don't understand the use of "that" in the expression "that songs", that normally goes with singular so why that with *songs*? Is it bad English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read this as an ellipsis:

> Such a crime ... Well, let's face it: in many ways it is **[a crime]** That songs of the quality of "Sparrows" or "Lucky Smile" should be obliged to wait 30 years for a release.

It's a simple "that" clause, same as in a sentence like "it's true that pigs can't fly". Also, what would be a single sentence here was punctuated as two, which is fine in very informal writing.